# Добавление изображения из галереи

Tags: android, imageview

Мне нужно, чтобы я могла добавить изображение из галереи в ImageView. Но почему-то у меня получается добавить его на эмуляторе, но при запуске приложения на реальном устройстве изображение не добавляется, просто появляется пустота.

```
ivEditProfil.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, GALLERY_REQUEST);
            }
    });

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case GALLERY_REQUEST:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    try {
                        final Uri imageUri = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                        final InputStream imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
                        final Bitmap selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);

                        ivEditProfil.setImageBitmap(selectedImage);
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Попробуйте добавить в файле манифеста перед тегом `<application>` такие строчки: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`